# How to link MySQL RDS in docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Instead of below `mysql` container DB link, I want to link `AWS Mysql RDS` in docker `yml file`. Is it possible?

```
 mysql_db:
      image: mysql:5.6
      container_name: shishir_db
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "xxxxxxxx"
        #MYSQL_USER: "shishir"
        #MYSQL_DATABASE: "shishir1"
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: "xxxxxxxx"
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
```

Comment: What do you mean "link"? MySQL RDS is a managed service to which your applications connect. Are you asking how to allow *network connections* from your container to your database's IP and Port perhaps?

Comment: What you posted seems to be an attempt to include a MySQL image in your container, *not* connect to RDS

Comment: When i do a "docker-compose up", a mysql container is getting created and application is getting connected to it, But i dont want this way, i have a RDS mysql DB with me, so whenevr i do a compose-up, the applications need to connect to RDS.

Comment: To achieve this, what changes i have do to in yml file? or what contents should i add in yml file instead of above mysql contents?

Comment: A MySQL container is created because that's what you asked for. Just don't use that image. I already answered what you should be looking for - set the network environment. Have you set up networking in your yml file?

Comment: I have not created any networking yet. Below is my entire yml file content. please let me know what changes i have to do.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways that you can link to a AWS RDS MySQL instance from your `docker-compose.yml`.

The first, and perhaps simplest way is to set environment variables on the containers that need access to the RDS MySQL instance. So for example, you could update your `OperationEngine` service definition to look something like:

```
OperationEngine:
 image: shishir/operationengine:${RELEASE_OTA_VERSION}
 container_name: operation_engine
 ports:
   - "8080:8080"
 environment:
  - DOCKER_HOST_IP: ${DOCKER_HOST_IP}
  - JAVA_OPTS: ${JAVA_OPTS}
  - MYSQL_HOST: "your-mysql-cname.rds.amazon.com"
  - MYSQL_USER: "username"
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
volumes:
  - ${HOME}/operationengine/logs/:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/
```

You can then update the configuration in that service to read database connection details from the environment e.g `${MYSQL_HOST}`.

The obvious downside to this approach is that you have connection details stored as plain text in your docker-compose.yml, which is not great, but may be acceptable depending on your requirements.

The 2nd approach (and the one I tend to favour) is to bind mount the database configuration into the running container.

Most applications support reading database connection details from a properties file. As an example: lets say that on start-up your application read from `/config/database.properties` and required the following properties to connect to the database:

```
config.db.host=your-mysql-cname.rds.amazon.com
config.db.user=foo
config.db.password=bar
```

I would setup my environment so that at runtime, I [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) a properties file that provides all of the required values to the container:

```
OperationEngine:
 volumes:
   - /secure/config/database.properties:/config/database.properties
```

The `/secure/config` directory is part of the filesystem on your Docker host. How that directory gets created and populated is up-to-you. Typically I approach this by having my environment setup scripts make the directory and then clone a private Git repository into this directory which contains the correct configuration for that environment. Naturally only those with the required permission levels can view the Git repositories that contain sensitive configuration details i.e. for production system.

Hope that helps.

Comment: could you please give any link which explain the format of yml file better?

Comment: @Shishir The official documentation is here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score 0):

No, i have not created networking in my yml file. Below is the entirecontent of my yml file, so what changes would be required?

mysql_db:
      image: mysql:5.6
      container_name: shishir_db
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "xxxxxxxx"
        #MYSQL_USER: "shishir"
        #MYSQL_DATABASE: "shishir1"
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: "xxxxxxxx"
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"

```
zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  container_name: zookeeper
  ports:
   - "2181:2181"

kafka:
  image: shishir/kafkaengine:0.10
  container_name: kafka
  links: 
   - zookeeper
  ports:
   - "9092:9092"
  environment:
   KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: ${DOCKER_HOST_IP}
   KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: ${DOCKER_HOST_IP}:2181
   KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
   KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: ${KAFKA_TOPICS}
   KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 12000
   KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS: 12000

flywaydb:
  image: shishir/flywaydb
  container_name: flywaydb
  links:
   - mysql_db

OperationEngine:
  image: shishir/operationengine:${RELEASE_OTA_VERSION}
  container_name: operation_engine
  links:
   - mysql_db
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  environment:
   DOCKER_HOST_IP: ${DOCKER_HOST_IP}
   JAVA_OPTS: ${JAVA_OPTS}
  volumes:
   - ${HOME}/operationengine/logs/:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/
```